# Checkbox Form Element: Displaying checkboxes value based on on/off

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I have a checkbox form element that uses taxonomy terms via `variable_get` as `#default_value`; storing the result. I don't want to overwrite value, I just want the form to render/display checked initially.

```
  $form['search_block_topic'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $topic_options,
    '#default_value' => variable_get('search_topic_options', $topic_options)
```

I tried
`'#return_value' => "checked"`
which doesn't work.

Comment: You mean besides the default value, you want another option to also be checked?

Comment: I would like all the check boxes to initially be checked but then store with a form_submit function.  Right now the store works fine but they start unchecked.